# Is there a part of Java's CDI that allows keeping track of whether specific clients received an event and resend if not?

Tags: java, events, jakarta-ee, java-8, cdi

We have events that we need to fire off to our WebSocket listeners. Most of our events need to have a guarantee delivery. If a WebSocket listener drops off (either before or during delivery), when they reconnect later, we need to resend them that event.

While I can design and write something myself to handle this, I'd prefer to use a built in part of CDI if that exists. Is there something to handle this?

Our current event code is:

Fire the event:

```
@Inject
@Added //”Added” is an event qualifier we create
Event<MyEvent> createdEvent;

@GET
@Produces( "application/json" )
public String fireEvent()
{
    //Tell any observers
    createdEvent.fireAsync( 
        new MyEvent(MyEvent.CREATED)
    );

...elided...
}
```

Sending the event to listeners:

```
@Asynchronous
private void notify(@ObservesAsync @Added MyEvent event)
{
    //Loop through and send to all listeners
    for ( Session session : sessions )
    {
        ...elided...

        //Tell push listener that this code was added
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText( event.toJSON() );

        ...elided...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not aware of such CDI part which would allow this but it seems to me that your problem is not CDI delivery - CDI always notifies the observer method (and has to know them upfront) - but rather `session.getBasicRemote().sendText( event.toJSON() );` which is basically your own code. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Siliarus I think JMS is what I want. The scenarios are: what if an event occurs and the user has not yet opened a websocket to listen for it? I need to send it to them when they finally do connect. And if the websocket fails partway through trying to send them the event, i need to retry.

Answer (score 0):

Events in CDI are reliable. Of course, when your application is shut down, the pending events are lost.

But be careful, the Event observers are only notified within an application instance. There is one exception - the Payara application server [implements a CDI Event bus](http://blog.payara.fish/microservice-choreography-with-the-payara-micro-clustered-cdi-event-bus) which is cluster-ready.

For a reliable event distribution try Apache Kafka.